# Symbolic multiplication of functions

Tags: matlab

I get an error when trying to multiply a symbolic function and a symbolic integral:

```
eta02=vpa(-i*omega2/((i*alpha2*lambda_0)^(2/3)),prec); %whatever
eta_inf2=vpa(vpa(((i*alpha2*lambda_0)^(1/3))*YMAX,prec)+eta02,prec); %whatever
%% 
syms lu
syms x
myairyf(lu)= airy(lu);
mybairyf(lu)=airy(2,lu);

Gi2(x)=-(mybairyf*int(myairyf,lu,[eta_inf2,(x)])-myairyf*int(mybairyf,lu,[eta02,(x)]));


Error using sym/subsindex (line 769)
Invalid indexing or function definition. When defining a function, ensure that the arguments are symbolic variables and the body of the
function is a SYM expression. When indexing, the input must be numeric, logical, or ':'.
```

How can this be done? Additionally, how could I plot Gi2(x), given that it's symbolic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the [`symfun`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html) function.

```
Gi2 = sumfun(-(mybairyf*int(myairyf,lu,[eta_inf2,(x)])-myairyf*int(mybairyf,lu,[eta02,(x)])), x);
```

Now `Gi2(val)` will evaluate the function for the value ´val´

Plotting then can be done by evaluating this function for the values you want to plot for, storing them in a vector, and plot the x and y values.

```
xvals = linspace(0,10,100);
yvals = Gi2(xvals);

figure
plot(xvals,vals)
```

Comment: Btw, is it possible to combine (multiplication, for instance) a symbolic function and a non-symbolic one? Would this make sense? I think the combination would be symbolic?

Comment: @Peter Yes this is possible, basically a non-symbolic function evaluates to a value, so you multiply a symbolic function with a value. This can make sense, if this other function is not dependent on the variables in the symbolic function. But multiplication of a symbolic function with a value is definitely possible and results in a symbolic function.